# How come WordPress 404 pages work when my server host blocks .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, hosting

I have two websites running WordPress on them and 404 pages work, but when I try to create my own .htaccess, it doesn't work and redirects to my web host's 404 page. Also, .htaccess is paid and I am on the free plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come WordPress 404 pages work when my server host blocks .htaccess?

WordPress 404 pages are entirely generated and served by WordPress/PHP. They having nothing to do with the server error documents.

> but when I try to create my own .htaccess, it doesn't work and redirects to my web host's 404 page.

Default server error documents are possibly defined by your host in the server config (that you don't have access to). Or, you are simply seeing Apache's default error documents?

But what's happened to your WordPress 404 page?

> **UPDATE:** Here's an example: Wordpress: click and Non-wordpress: click.

Having seen an example of the "non-WordPress" site and "web host's" 404 page, it would seem that your host has defined a simple error document on your domain (that you cannot override) that issues a meta-refresh to the web host's 404 page on a different domain.

The host has probably defined this as a single directive in the server config, something like:

```
ErrorDocument 404 "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;http://errors.biz.nf/404.php\" /></head><body></body></html>"
```

The initial request for a non-existent file on your site returns a 404 and the following response body (line breaks added for clarity):

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;http://errors.biz.nf/404.php" />
</head><body></body></html>
```

As soon as the browser receives this, the browser then issues a second request for `http://errors.biz.nf/404.php` (a different domain), which also issues a 404 (this is the web host's 404 page).

This is no doubt an unfortunate caveat of the "free plan".

Comment: Here's an example: _Wordpress:_ [click](http://leafcomputer.co.nf/ageghe49a84) and _Non-wordpress:_ [click](http://forleaf.co.nf/ageghe49a84).

Comment: Ah ok, so when you see the "web host's 404 page", that is an entirely separate (non-WordPress) site. I've updated my answer.